# How do I enforce a minimum test coverage percentage in my Foundry Code Repositories?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I not only want to write unit tests in my Foundry Code Repository, but I want to enforce a minimum amount of coverage for checks to pass.

It's a best practice to ensure that I'm covering at least a certain fraction of my code with unit tests, but tests don't seem to be a requirement in standard repositories.

How do I accomplish my two testing goals within my Foundry Code Repository?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PyTest Coverage](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to compute coverage and enforce a minimum percentage.

1. Add the following to your repo's `meta.yml` :

```yaml
...

test:
  requires:
    - pytest-cov
...
```

**Note: this is *outside* the requirements section in a section of its own.**

2. Create a `pytest.ini` file at `/transforms-python/src/pytest.ini` with the following contents:

```
[pytest]
addopts = --cov=<<package name, e.g. myproject>> --cov-report term --cov-fail-under=100
```

**Note: you can tune the enforcement percentage down from 100 if you'd like**

Your tests will now fail, even if they include *some* unit tests, if that coverage threshold is below your configured value:

[image: checks]